# case class to json (partial) conversion

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have following case class:

```
case class Test(name: String, email: String, phone: String)
```

So in order to be able to serialize to JSON I wrote:

```
implicit val testWrites: Writes[Test] = (
  (__ \ "name").write[String] and
    (__ \ "email").write[String] and
    (__ \ "phone").write[String]
  )(unlift(Test.unapply))
```

I want to use this as something like DTO object, so I can exclude some fields while serizalizing.
Let's we say I want to show only `name` and `email` fields.

I tried something like this:

```
implicit val testWrites: Writes[Test] = (
  (__ \ "name").write[String] and
    (__ \ "email").write[String]
  )(unlift(Test.unapply))
```

But this is giving me compile error -> `Application does not take parameters`.

Does anyone know what is the problem, and how I can achieve mentioned idea?

Comment: The reason is that unapply method returns specified tuple, so you have to fill gaps with placeholders.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Play JSON combinators often take advantage of the `unapply` method that is automatically generated in the companion object of a case class.

For your case class:

```
case class Test(name: String, email: String, phone: String)
```

The unapply method looks like this:

```
def unapply(test: Test): Option[(String, String, String)] = Some((test.name, test.email, test.phone))
```

It returns the field values of the case class tupled and wrapped in `Option`. For example:

```
val test: Test = Test("John Sample", "fake@email.com", "1-800-NOT-NULL")

Test.unapply(test) // returns Some(("John Sample", "fake@email.com", "1-800-NOT-NULL"))
```

`unlift` transforms the `unapply` function into a `PartialFunction[Test, (String, String, String)]`, which is then used to map an instance of `Test` to a tuple, which is then used to serialize the class.

You need not use `Test.unapply`. It's only convenient to use it when you want to serialize the entire class. If you only want some fields, you can define a similar function `Test => Option[(String, String)]`:

```
def simpleExtractor(test: Test): Option[(String, String)] = Some(test.name, test.email)
```

And then use it in the JSON combinators:

```
implicit val testWrites: Writes[Test] = (
    (__ \ "name").write[String] and
    (__ \ "email").write[String]
)(unlift(simpleExtractor))
```

---

Similarly, JSON `Reads` often takes advantage of the automatically generated `apply` method for case classes. `Test.apply _` is a function `(String, String, String) => Test`-- basically the opposite as `unapply`, as you might have guessed. The JSON API assembles a tuple with the fields specified in the `Reads`, then passes that tuple through `Test.apply _`, which produces the deserialized `Test`.

To do generate a `Reads` that will only read two fields you could define another apply-like function:

```
def simpleBuilder(name: String, email: String): Test = Test(name, email, "default")

implicit val testReads: Reads[Test] = (
    (__ \ "name").read[String] and
    (__ \ "email").read[String]
)(unlift(simpleBuilder _))
```

Though personally I prefer not to do this, and define a default value within the `Reads` itself:

```
implicit val testReads: Reads[Test] = (
    (__ \ "name").read[String] and
    (__ \ "email").read[String] and 
    (__ \ "phone").read[String].orElse(Reads.pure("default"))
)(unlift(Test.apply _))
```

Comment: Can you please explain me this part a little bit more: ``It returns the field values of the case class tupled and wrapped in Option. unlift transforms the unapply function into a PartialFunction[Test, (String, String, String)], which is then used to map an instance of Test to a tuple, which is then used to serialize the class.``. How ``mapping`` to instance of ``Test`` class to touple is called at all, and in which order statements are executed there? I am new to scala and this syntax is pretty confusing for me

Comment: The JSON API is doing most of that work for you. The key is just understanding what it's looking for from you. In this case, a function similar to `unapply` that returns an optional tuple. I suggest trying some of this in the REPL. If you run `play console`, you'll be able to execute all of this code with the Play libs and see the return types. (or `activator console` if 2.3)